# clEnqueueReadBuffer / clEnqueueWriteBuffer: force pinned memory mode

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

In order to have a full speed communication with openCL, it is necessary to use pinned memory from the host side. Such memory will never be paginated and can be obtain by using clCreateBuffer() with the CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag then clEnqueueMapBuffer.

But one may know an object is already in pinned memory (because it was created with, for example, those functions but in another context) and therefore want to use clEnqueueReadBuffer()/clEnqueueWriteBuffer() at full speed. Unfortunately, if the memory was not pinned in the current context, the object is not considered as pinned and the data-rate is not maximum.

**How to say that an object is already in pinned memory to OpenCL?**

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion on this question is the OpenCL SDKs must maintain their own set of flags to know if they allocated the buffer or not, and therefore if it is safe to assume if it is pinned or not. They seem to conservatively assume that an externally allocated buffer is not pinned nor aligned.

I tried to match the benchmark's bandwidth for buffers *allocated* using `clCreateBuffer` and buffers *using* memory allocated externally, either using `clCreateBuffer` on a different context or manually pinned and aligned memory, and the first always seems to perform better for both AMD and nvidia.